# powershell reading an excel to match combination in rows then output a property

Tags: powershell

I've got an excel table as closely shown below:

```
Name Position Shift Access1  Access2
A    X        W     AA1      AAA2
A    Y        W     AA3,AA4  AAA3
A    Z        V     AA5
B    X        W     BB1      BBB2,BBB3
B    Y        V     BB3,BB4  BBB5
B    Z        V     BB6      BBB7
```

I've got an input that captures Name, Position and Shift. What i need is to construct the script logic that if the combination of the ROW = Name+Position+Shift matches, then output the Access1 and Access2, notice some have 2 values in the Access1 and Access2. So for example, if A + Y + W then output should be AA3, AA4 and AAA3. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: What have you tried so far? PowerShell works easier with CSV input by the way.

Comment: Thanks Matt, I got it going, after a lot of attempts, using Where-Object, then select-object, then foreach. Yes have converted that to a csv for easy reading. Just wanting to ask if we can avoid using a csv, that is a long list, if there are other alternatives, if we used a table or array inside the script itself? i'm not sure. Thanks again.

Comment: Then you need to look at some [examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17406842/powershell-writing-data-into-excel-file) of reading Excel files first.